# Passing a variable from the store to my API

Tags: bigcommerce

Each category page on the Bigcommerce store has a unique id: `%%GLOBAL_CatId%%`

I need to pass this variable, which I cannot possibly know before hand, to my API script. I'm using an include for my script so I've tried several variations of the following but I can't get anything to work:

```
%%Include.http://example.com/api.php?catid=%%GLOBAL_CatId%%%%
```

Is this possible and how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was informed by API support that this is NOT possible.